# Full width for wordpress theme expositio

Tags: css, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I'm using the wp-theme Expositio:

http://expositio.wpshower.com/sample-page/

and I want to make the text and other content (galleries) to fill the whole screen and not just like 80 % from the left side. 
I already tried to change all width settings in the style.css to 100% but nothing changed at all!

Where else could I look for the hidden width-restriction?

Comment: My guess is that you need to change the `max-width` property.

Comment: On the link you provided, there very clearly is.

Comment: yes sorry i got it wrong. Changed the max-width property like said below, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

On line 1356 style.css is the rule `body.page.hentry, .page-content`with the property `max-width: 620px;`change the to 100%. Must working.

Comment: Is it possible that there is a whitespace or another placeholder, that prohibits that the content is shown on 100% of the screen?

Comment: 1) On line 1356 style.css is the rule body.page.hentry, .page-content with the property max-width: 620px;change the to 100%.
2) On line 1054 style.css  is the rule body.page .hentry, .page-content with the property width: 67.391304348%; change the to 100%
3) Enjoy! =)

Answer (score 1):

This works on the link you provided OP

```
body.page .hentry, .page-content {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The other answers seem to have missed the `width` property along with `max-width`. I'd recommend that you make the changes on a separate stylesheet as this makes updating the theme easier. Also make sure your new styles override or replace the existing ones obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, on line 1054 of your style.css

```
body.page .hentry, .page-content {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wow, I finally found it. It wasn't enough to set the body.page hentry, .page-content to 100% but also the

```
    .site {
        min-width: 100%;
    }
```

that finally made it.
thanks for all your answers